# WinJS: Efficient xml parsing

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, winjs

I currently have the bellow code to get some data from an xml feed.

```
        var title = []
    var start = []
    var end = []
    var xml = result;
    var channel = xml.split('<channel')[1].split('>')[0].split('"')[1]
    var xmlLength = xml.split("<programme>").length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < xmlLength; i++) {
        var event = xml.split("<event>")[i + 1].split("</event>")[0];
        title[i] = programme.split("<title>")[1].split("</title>")[0];
        var rs = programme.split("<start>")[1].split("</start>")[0].split(/\-|\s/);
        var re = programme.split("<end>")[1].split("</end>")[0].split(/\-|\s/);
        start[i] = new Date(rs.slice(0, 3).join('/') + ' ' + rs[3]);
        end[i] = new Date(re.slice(0, 3).join('/') + ' ' + re[3]);
    }
    setListView(event, start, end, channel)
```

This currently works but it doesn't seem very efficient. I wonder if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you should be using the classes in the [Windows.Web.Syndication namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.syndication.aspx) as it looks like you are doing RSS related things, but you could also use the [raw XML API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to parse the `XML` on your own. Have you considered using `jQuery.parseXML()`?

Check it out here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am am now using JSON instead.